# Details about sudo commands executed by all user

Tags: sudo, logs

From which log can I get details about sudo commands executed by any user. It should contain the working directory, command, user. 
It will be helpful if you could provide me a shell script to do so

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Depending on your distro; simply:

```
$ sudo grep sudo /var/log/secure
```

or

```
$ sudo grep sudo /var/log/auth.log
```

which gives:

```
Nov 14 09:07:31 vm1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=gareth uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/19 ruser=gareth rhost=  user=gareth
Nov 14 09:07:37 vm1 sudo: gareth : TTY=pts/19 ; PWD=/home/gareth ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/yum update
Nov 14 09:07:53 vm1 sudo: gareth : TTY=pts/19 ; PWD=/home/gareth ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/grep sudo /var/log/secure
```

The user running the command is after the `sudo:` - `gareth` in this case.

`PWD` is the directory.

`USER` is the user that `gareth` is running as - `root` in this example.

`COMMAND` is the command ran.

Therefore, in the example above, `gareth` used `sudo` to run `yum update` and then ran this example.  Before that he typed in the incorrect password.

Note also that there may be rolled log files, like `/var/log/secure*`

On newer systems:

```
$ sudo journalctl _COMM=sudo
```

gives a very similar output.

Comment: This is a great answer for users that use `sudo` for each individual command, but for a user that does `sudo -i` (for example), you get no such details. At least on my Debian-based system, I see `session opened` and `session closed` - but nothing in between. I wonder if that's down to a setting in the `sudoers` file?

Answer (score 0):

A "results filter" for Gareth's solution. (for those that arrived by title of post, not description)

Gives you a clean list of commands-only, run as sudo, by all users.

```
$sudo journalctl _COMM=sudo  | sed -e '/COMMAND/!d' -e 's/.*COMMAND=//' -e 's/.*bin\///'
```

Workaround if sed unavailable

```
$sudo journalctl _COMM=sudo | grep COMMAND
```

C&P results into Google sheets

In cell B1 C&P this formula

```
=arrayformula(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,".*AND=/usr/bin/(.*)","$1"))
```